# How do I connect to oracle database using a service name?

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to an external database (not my localhost database).

My login details are (made up details of course). I use these login details to login successfully using oracle's sql developer.

```
Username: COOLDB123
Password: ThisIsADB123
Hostname: oracle.mywebsite.com
Port: 1521
Service name (NOT SID, I don't use a SID): pdb.oracle.mywebsite.com
```

---

**login-script.php**

```
<?php
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle.mywebsite.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=pdb.oracle.mywebsite.com)))" ;

    if($c = OCILogon("COOLDB123", "ThisIsADB123", $db))
    {
        echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.\n";
        OCILogoff($c);
    }
    else
    {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Connection failed.";
    }
?>
```

---

However, I get the error:

```
Warning: ocilogon(): ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 4
Connection failed.
```

I know for a fact the details are correct because I can log into my database using Oracle's SQL developer. What am I doing wrong? I am suspecting that in my `$db` part I am putting `SID` instead of the service name. However, I am unsure of the syntax for the service name.

Answer (score 1):

To add the service name I have to change `$db` to:

```
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle.mywebsite.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=pdb.oracle.mywebsite.com)))" ;
```